# Pork In A Jew’s Home

Tags: non-kosher-species

Are Jews allowed to have pork inside their home? For example, if a Jew’s pet has pork inside their vitamins or dog food, are jews  allowed keep that product inside their home?

Comment: Yes, and this answer explains why, and you can follow his link to star-k and get all the sources: https://kesher.org.uk/knowledge-base/kosher-dog-food/

Comment: Keeping it in their home and giving it to their pets are two different questions